# Make business central webhooks use a authentication for its notifications

Tags: dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I have to provied an API to receive webhook notifications from business central. To give this some kind of protection I would like to use basic auth on it.

Is there a way to make BC365 use basic auth when sending notifications? I tried to include the credentials into the registered url like this, but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
{
    "notificationUrl": "https://user:pwd@url/items",
    "resource": "/api/v2.0/companies(xyz)/items",
    "clientState": "myState"
}
```

Any other ideas, how have this endpoint not completely open to public exploration...?

Answer (score 1):

The URL in `notificationUrl` needs to be open access.

Apart from the mandatory handshake when registering your subscriber the only extra security available is to include a `clientState` in the registration.

This `clientState` will then be included in all the notifications sent to your `notificationUrl` and you can use that to validate if the request comes from your subscription and not somewhere else.

I suggest you use a value for `clientState` that resembles a `clientSecret` for OAuth2 authentication.

For more information check you the [documentation for working with webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/dynamics-subscriptions).